# @media handheld не работает?

Tags: css3

Кто-нибудь знает почему `@media handheld` не работает, в то время как `@media screen`  и другие работают нормально?

Comment: Exctac, пожалуйста, приведите пример кода и укажите в вопросе, на каком устройстве проверяли работу.

Comment: @VenZell, пример не требуется. Речь о стандартном медиа-запросе.

Comment: @Qwertiy, пример, как раз, требуется. Вы полностью исключаете банальную ошибку в коде?

Comment: Дело в том, что это значение не поддерживается устройствами. По мере того, как подобные устройства стали приблежаться по характеристикам к компьютерам, подобное отношение к ним становилось всё менее актуальным. Значение стало игнорироваться, и вместо него следует проверять размеры экрана и/или ориентацию.

Comment: пример кода не думаю что стоит приводить, я с мануала копировал, как хошь проверял, но не пашет! соглашусь VenZell, где то на буржуйских сайтах прочитал что то подобное, но решил и сюда написать на всякий и удостовериться! всем спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, не работает. Надо проверять размеры экрана и другие свойства вместо того, чтобы определять устройство.

По мере того, как подобные устройства стали приблежаться по характеристикам к компьютерам, подобное отношение к ним становилось всё менее актуальным. Значение стало игнорироваться, и вместо него следует проверять размеры экрана и/или ориентацию.

То же самое касается браузеров - лучше проверять поддержку фич, а не версию браузера.

> http://habrahabr.ru/post/107764/
>   Строка с media=«screen» соотвествует обычному компьютеру, media=«handheld» — это мобильное устройство. Новые устройства отказываются от такого подхода и необходимо использовать запросы внутри атрибута media.